# Does Vinay know Anjali before meeting her at the jewelry shop?

Tags: plot-explanation, jewel-thief

At the beginning of the famous Indian movie [Jewel Thief (1967)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewel_Thief),
Vinay (Dev Anand) is seen going to a jewelry shop and talking to the owner about employment. After being rejected, he steps out of the shop, and at the same time, the owner's daughter -- Anjali(Tanuja) -- is seen entering the shop. After this, there is a song sequence where Dev Anand encounters a group of girls (including Anjali) on a country side road. The song sequence suggests that Dev Anand was intentionally walking in front of the car to tease girls. After a little hustle, they are acquainted.

Later, when Dev Anand is finally employed at the same jewelry shop,
Tanuja pays a visit, and Dev Anand tries to sell necklaces to her. However, after a little playing she reveals that she is the owner's daughter, and Dev Anand shows as if he did not know this, and is completely surprised.

Was the surprise true or false? 
Did he know her well and that is why he followed her after being rejected by his father? Was he looking for another way to get in, and then he tried to play it smart by pretending that he did not know who she really was? 
Or was it a mere coincidence that Dev Anand happened to be on the same road as Tanuja, and teasing some random girls soon after he was denied a job at her father's shop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that Vinay did not know Anjali before their meeting at the jewelry shop.
I infer this from analyzing the character of Vinay. He doesn't appear like someone who will use crooked methods. Also, regarding the sog sequence, I think it was a mere coincidence, intentionally plotted by the director to create mystery.